# Brave not opening using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, brave

I am trying to run my selenium code on brave instead of chrome because I just prefer brave. But when I try to do it I keep on facing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/WebScraping/Test.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)
  File "/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/WebScraping/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/WebScraping/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/WebScraping/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/WebScraping/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/WebScraping/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
```

My code goes as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


driver_path = '/Users/vasu/Desktop/Code/chromedriver'
brave_path = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
option.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)

driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://cms.instructure.com'
driver.get(url)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Use absolute driver path.

Comment: what do you mean by `absolute`?

Comment: The full path to the executable files. Look at the link for the duplicate it has an example.